Why don't I get search options for the videos in one of my Youtube channels?
I've created a new Youtube channel, I already have 2 of them. In the other 2 channels, I have search options for the videos inside the channel (oldest, most recent, popular) , but in the new one, I dont have any option.
Why is that? Is it a configuration option? Do new channels don't get that option or something? Any ideas?
